# Puppet class overloading

Tags: deployment, puppet

Does puppet support class constructor overloading? if it doesn't, what's the best practice here for my case below?

I basically want to have my dummy:simple_node takes different parameters:

```
class dummy::simple_node($param1)

class dummy::simple_node($param1, $param2)

class dummy::simple_node($param1, $param2, $param3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not, and only has basic inheritance support.

I would use hiera and/or conditionals, and also supply defaults for each param, that way you can ignore / filter them based on what you are trying to accomplish.

Without knowing your end goal and/or seeing additional code, it would be impossible to suggest an actual best practice.